# Endless text scale css animation

Tags: css

Im trying to make effect of endless text scale animation. How do I get rid of jump between 50% and 51%? I would like to apply that state change immediately and then continue to scale in from 0 to 1.

So the effect should be be: text gradually scales to 300 and then jumps to 0 and scales to 300 gradually again

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

p:hover {
  padding: 40px;
  display: inline-flex;
  animation: endless-in infinite 4s linear;
}

@keyframes endless-in {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(300);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  51% {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>some text</p>
</div>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

Comment: Don't leave a "gap" of a full percent between the two steps, but make the 51 `50.001%` instead.

Comment: @CBroe works like a charm! I thought it accepts only integers, tyvm - I don't need to overcomplex now because I solved it with 2 different animations (one `infinite` with delay and another that stucks in `forwards` state)

Comment: @CBroe you should post your comment as an answer and OP should accept as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I get rid of jump between 50% and 51%?

Close the "gap" of one percent between those two steps, by using a smaller value for the second one - instead of `51%`, make that `50.001%`.

Depending on your animation duration, that one percent can be a "long" time, and in that time you will see the specified property transition between the two values (same as happened between 0% and 50% to begin with, only there you *wanted* to see the effect.)

Decimals are allowed for the percentages, and help to keep that gap minimal in a case like this.

Comment: thanks for the answer, didn't know that `50.001%` is a valid value